# How I use return value as cell no

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I wrote the below formula to get the cell address.

```
=(ADDRESS((MATCH(0,C3:C14,0)+2),3))
```

it returns `$C$12`

Now I want to add or sum value  with in the range. The range is C3:C12.

Formula should be like this

```
=Sum(C3:(ADDRESS((MATCH(0,C3:C14,0)+2),3))
```

But it's not working. What I did wrong?

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Thanks Guys....After using below formula its working fine. Now I facing another .
Here is the formula:-

`=IF(VALUE(IFERROR((MATCH(0,C3:C14,0)),0))= 0,SUM(C3:INDEX(C:C,MATCH(0,C3:C15,0)+1)),SUM(C3:C14))`

Above formula is working fine when its found some 0 in column C but its giving #NA when its couldn't found any 0 in Column C.
Result should be the sum of column range which is (C3:C14)

Comment: Not a programming question so not really suited to this board but: =Sum(C3:INDEX(C:C,MATCH(0,C3:C14,0)+2))

Comment: @Rory community consensus is that Excel Formulas _are_ a form of programming, and are on topic.

Comment: Fair enough. Seems weird to me (I thought that's what SuperUser was for), but never mind. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUM(C3:INDEX(C:C,MATCH(0,C3:C14,0)+2))
```